# How do they quantify stuff in a natural way when asking to buy something?

Tags: meaning, translation

"Buying something" is just to put it in a special context so it's easy for you to think back.

I'm new to German so it's quite struggling for me to buy something in terms of specifying the quantity. For example, I would say, as translated from English:

> Eine Flasche Wasser bitte.

instead of just

> Wasser bitte.

because it sounds kind of awkward when you think in English term, normally we ask for "a bottle of water" rather than just "I wanna buy (some) water". But then, the former way sounds kind of long and I'm not sure if native speakers bother to say that many syllables.

Same thing for buying cigarette in the Supermarket for example, how do you say it naturally? I would normally say

> Und ich kaufe gern eine Schachtel Zigaretten

But it sounds kind of long again, I've seen native speakers mumbling something very brief and the Kassiererin still managed to understand lol.

Comment: "that many syllables" - somehow, when I count syllables in "a bottle of water", I arrive at six (unless I make sure to speak really sloppily, swallowing the end of *bottle* and *water*), which is the same as in "eine Flasche Wasser".

Comment: I think what you heard at the supermarket was *Und eine/einmal Marlboro/Camel/Gauloises etc., bitte* which literally translates into *And one Marlboro/Camel/Gauloises please.* Of course a package, not a single cigarette nor a carton.

Comment: German is an extensive language. If you translate anything form most other languages into German, then the German version is almost always longer then the original text. This strongly depends on the other language. But if you compare English and German, you will find, that the German version of the same text is significant longer than the English version. (In average 10-20% longer, but for short texts the German version can even have more than the double length)

Comment: Its ok to say "ein Wasser bitte" or  "eine Flasche Wasser bitte".

Comment: In your example `Wasser bitte` you can ommit the quantifier if it is a well known default. For example if a restaurant offers only a glass of water then you can use it when asked for a drink. If several different quantities are sold or purchasing of multiple items is common that you at least specify the quantity but also often the quantifier.

Comment: "I'd like to buy ..." transates as "Ich möchte ... kaufen", not as "ich kaufe gern ..." (the latter means "I enjoy buying ...")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not at all long for a native German. Any of these are fine depending on circumstances. If you want to use the last sentence when buying cigarettes in a shop you would say:

> Ich hätte gern eine Schachtel Zigaretten.

, otherwise the way you wrote it, you'd inform somebody that you enjoy buying a package of cigarettes (e.g. after somebody asked you to do so).

Now, what would a native say? In a restaurant if you order just *Wasser*, you'd get a glass of water. So if you want a bottle of water you have to specify that.

> Eine Flasche Wasser bitte.

is perfectly fine, but likely you also want to specify *mit/ohne Kohlensäure (stilles)*.

I don't smoke, but from what I saw/heard, people would usually use the brand name to refer to a package of cigarettes. So you could say:

> Eine Schachtel  [brand name] bitte.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the quantifier of whatever the product is packed in. For drinks that is typically bottles (unless you’re buying Capri-Sonne or similar, in which case it’s bag), for products sold apiece it’s just a number followed by the word, for those sold by weight it’s their weight (note that in Austria food is weighed in *Deka,* short for *dekagram,* rather than in grams), for others it’ll depend on whether they are packed in *Packungen, Schachteln, Tüten, Säcken, Sackerln, Körben, Töpfen …* Some even have more exotic-seeming quantifiers, e.g. certain brands of margarine for baking are quantified in *Stangen.*

> Eine Flasche Wasser bitte.

This example of your’s is not only perfectly correct but also perfectly idiomatic. Basically, any noun that can describe a package quantity can also be used as a quantifier. Here are a few examples:

> Eine Packung Kaugummi
>
> Eine Tüte Chips (that’s crisps in English) (Germany exclusive; Austria uses *Packung)*
>
> Ein Sackerl Kartoffeln (Austria and Bavaria primarily)
>
> Ein Korb Erdbeeren
>
> Ein Topf Geranien
>
> 100 Gramm Fleischwurst (In Austria: 10 Deka)
>
> Zwei Weißwürste

Comment: Attention! This depends on the region where you live. In Austria you never use the word »Tüte« (except you are a tourist or immigrant from Germany)! So in Austria it is »eine *Packung* Chips«, and in Austria you don't buy sliced sausages in »Gramm« but in »Deka« (short for »Dekagramm«; 10 g = 1 dag). So there you don't buy »100 Gramm Wurst« but »Zehn Deka Wurst«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In einer Wiener Trafik wurde ich (Dt.) einmal _„Wolln's a Sackerl?“_ gefragt. Als ich nicht schnell genug antwortete, schob der Herr ostentativ und auf Hochdeutsch ein _„Ob Sie eine Tüte möchten?“_ hinterher. Und wir haben beide herzlich gelacht.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Die meisten Österreicher beherrschen mindestens drei Sprachen. Alle sprechen den jeweiligen lokalen Dialekt, das ist in den meisten Fällen die eigentliche Muttersprache eines Österreichers. Fast alle beherrschen auch österreichisches Hochdeutsch (das sich vielerorts in Grammatik und Vokabular aber erheblich vom Dialekt unterscheidet, diesen Unterschied sollte man nicht unterschätzen). Ein ebenfalls sehr großer Teil kann sich in Notfällen sogar in der Sprache unserer Lieblingsnachbarn (also in deutschem Deutsch) verständlich machen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Fleischwurst (bzw was ich darunter verstehe) wird idR nicht in Scheiben verkauft. Allerdings auch eher nicht in Gramm sondern in Stück. Wird Käse in Österreich auch in *Deka* verkauft? Ich wollte diese Antwort übrigens nicht regional spezifisch sehen sondern lediglich Begriffe auflisten; dass sie alle in Deutschland aber ggf nicht alle in FL/A/CH/L/BE/Südtirol verwendet werden ist meiner Herkunft geschuldet …

Comment: @Jan: Den Begriff »Fleischwurst« kenne ich so nicht. (Woraus, wenn nicht aus Fleisch, sollte man denn sonst Würste machen?) In Ö teilt man Würste in zwei Kategorien: A) Frankfurter, Debreziner, Klobasse, Krainer usw.: Das sind kleine Würste (»Würstel«), die man vor dem Verzehr in heißem Wasser ziehen lässt (nicht kochen, sonst platzen die Würstel auf!). Man isst ein Stück oder ein Paar wenn es noch heiß ist, indem man es mit der Hand nimmt und ein Stück davon abbeißt. Dazu Senf und eine Semmel. So ein Würstel hat einen so kleinen Durchmesser, dass es bequem in den Mund eines Kindes passt.

Comment: (Forst.:) B) Extrawurst, Wiener, Krakauer, Polnische usw: Das sind Würste, die kalt gegessen werden. (»Stangenwürste, Jausenwürste«) Die Stangen haben typischerweise ein Durchmesser von 8 cm, sind also gleich groß wie Semmeln (Tatsächlich haben sich Bäcker und Fleischhauer mal auf einen gemeinsamen Durchmesser geeinigt, der aber nur eine Übereinkunft, keine echte Norm ist). Die Stangen werden in dünne Scheiben geschnitten, diese Scheiben legt man üblicherweise in eine aufgeschnittene Semmel (die man dann »Wurstsemmel« nennt).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast [Fleischwurst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyoner). Wahrscheinlich also Stangenwurst laut deiner Aufteilung. Kennst du noch einen Quantifizierer, der österreichspezifisch ist? *Tüte* ist ja offensichtlich ein Teutonismus, während *Packung* in beiden Varietäten verwendet wird (und es durchaus vorstellbar, aber weniger wahrscheinlich ist, dass in D von einer »Packung Chips« gesprochen wird). Auf meine Käsefrage im Kommentar bist du leider auch nicht eingegangen …

Comment: @Jan: Das Gewicht von Lebensmitteln wird in Österreich prinzipiell in Deka angegeben. Das trifft nicht nur auf Fleisch und Wurst, sondern natürlich auch auf Käse zu. Die Wagen in den Supermärkten zeigen aber Gramm an, und auch auf der Rechnung wird das Gewicht in Gramm ausgedruckt. Aber mündlich wird so gut wie nie von Gramm, sondern immer von Deka gesprochen.

Comment: @Jan: Ein »Sack Kartoffeln« ist in Österreich ein Sack mit 20 oder mehr Kilogramm. Häufig kauft man aber kleinere Mengen, das wäre dann eher ein »Sackerl Erdäpfel« (Sackerl ist *kein* Dialektwort, sondern österreichisches Hochdeutsch). Die deutsche »Einkaufstüte« heißt in Österreich »Plastiksackerl«: http://derstandard.at/2000014958465/EU-Parlament-beschliesst-Reduktion-von-Plastiksackerln und https://www.global2000.at/plastiksackerl-verbot-es-geht-auch-ohne und http://diepresse.com/home/politik/eu/4719367/EU-verbietet-kostenlose-Plastiksackerl-ab-2018

Comment: @Jan: Gemüse wird in Österreich oft im Bund verkauft, ich weiß jedoch nicht, ob das in Deutschland anders ist: (»Ein Bund Radieschen«)

Answer (score 1):

German is more formal than English, so you use quantifiers in the language more than you would in English. Basically, if there is any available quantifier, use it.

You're on the right track with expressions such as "Eine Flasche Wasser bitte," and " eine Schachtel Zigaretten." Just realize that it is normal German, even though using the equivalents in English might sound "heavy." What would sound strange to German ears if you *don't* use the quantifiers. Then your German would sound "light" to a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The quantifier allows to differentiate between specific and non-specific amounts. If the amount is important, e.g. when shopping, use a quantifier:

> Ich kaufe *eine Flasche* Wasser
>
> I buy *one bottle* of water (not more, not less)

If you want to make a general statement, that is not related to a specific amount, you do not quantify:

> Ich mag *Zigaretten*
>
> I like *cigarettes* (in general)

Any further additions (like *bitte* or *gerne* in your example) are part of constructions to convey politeness, but not required for the sentence per se.